# Reload tableView from CoreData after modal view dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, mvvm

I'm creating simple Todo app using CoreData and MVVM pattern. When I create new task and modal view disappear, the tableView not reload with new data, only after app restarting. I use custom delegate for reloading:

**AddNewTaskController**

```
@IBAction func save(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    switch viewModel.validation() {
    case .success(_):
        viewModel.save { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(_):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.refreshTableDelegate.refreshTable()
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            case .error(let error):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.errorAlert(withMessage: error)
                }
            }
        }
    case .error(let errorMsg):
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.errorAlert(withMessage: errorMsg)
        }
    }
}
```

**TasksListController**

```
private func getTasks() {
    viewModel.getTasks { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(_):
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        case .error(let errorMsg):
            DispatchQueue.main.sync { [unowned self] in
                self.errorAlert(withMessage: errorMsg)
            }
        }
    }
}

func refreshTable() {
    getTasks()
}
```

Anybody know how to refresh tableView with delegate and MVVM?

Comment: If you're using Core Data why aren't you also using NSFetchedResultsController? It exists specifically for this use-case.

Comment: because if I will ise it, I must get logic to view controller, it's not compatible with MVVM

Comment: There's no reason a View Model can't conform to NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate.

Comment: So where is it failing? Did you try putting a breakpoint and checking where the flow is breaking, if `self.tableView.reloadData()` is getting executed?

Comment: @Dare I changed my code and now using NSFetcedResultController with MVVM. thank u for hint